# Finding $\ln2$ from $\log(1-z)$ power series

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, power-series

I'm currently trying to determine how to find a formula for calculating $\ln2$ from the derivation of the power series $\log(1-z)$. I guess what I am confused about is whether or not the $\log$ is base $e$ or if that is even relevant. If not, would it simply be plugging in $z=-1$ into the power series expansion $$\log(1-z) = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k} $$ or if there's another step involved.
All help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Plugging in $z=-1$ will technically work, but will give you a very slowly converging series.  In practice, one trick I've seen to get better convergence is to write $\ln 2 = \ln (1 - (-1/3)) - \ln (1 - 1/3)$ and evaluate the two terms on the right by plugging in $z=-\frac{1}{3}$ and $z=\frac{1}{3}$ respectively in that formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends upon how much you know about the equality$$\log(1-z)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}k.\tag1$$If it turns out that you know that it holds whenever $|z|<1$ and $z\ne1$, then, yes, you can put $z=-1$. If you only know that $(1)$ holds when $|z|<1$, you can use the fact that$$\log(2)=-\log\left(\frac12\right)=-\log\left(1-\frac12\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k2^k}.$$

Answer (score 2):

First, the formula $$\log (1-z) = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}$$ corresponds to a natural logarithm (base $e$).  In mathematics, $\log$ is almost always the natural logarithm, even if it not written $\ln$.  Mathematicians will write $\log_{10}$ if they need to specify a base-$10$ logarithm.

Next, the simplest thing to do if you want $\log 2$ is to let $z = 1/2$ and observe
$$\log(1 - 1/2) = \log(1/2) = - \log 2.$$  Thus $$\log 2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k 2^k}.$$  This series converges reasonably quickly; only $17$ terms are needed to get $6$-digit accuracy.

In general, convergence is faster the closer $z$ is to $0$.

Comment: This is just how I would do it.